AMD microcode update for sinkclose in Jammy(22.04)?
AMD has provided microcode fixes for their EPYC CPUs in their July microcode drops into linux-firmware. These are important to close the Sinkclose SMM hole.
Any reason these are not shipped (yet?) as updates in Jammy (22.04)?
Other Linux distros have included these already.

Debian is already released https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-31315
I hope this will be released soon.

These seem to be released now (since 21 October 2024) :
CVE : https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-31315
USN : https://usn.ubuntu.com/USN-7077-1
